# Kompozer gives an error when runned under 12.10 amd64

Tags: 64-bit, 12.10

I [downloaded kompozer](http://netcologne.dl.sourceforge.net/project/kompozer/current/0.8b3/linux-i686/kompozer-0.8b3.nl.gcc4.2-i686.tar.gz) extracted it and  run kompozer like `./kompozer`
 
So then I get this error in the gnome-terminal

```
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"
/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/menuproxies/libappmenu.so: wrong ELF-class: ELFCLASS64

(kompozer-bin:8651): Gtk-WARNING **: Failed to load type module: /usr/lib/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/menuproxies/libappmenu.so
```

How can i get Kompozer to work under 12.10 amd64?

**note:** The error above had some dutch words in them so i translated it!

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with kompozer on ubuntu 12.10.
But, there is a solution to the problem.
Just visit this [link](http://www.howtoforge.com/the-perfect-desktop-xubuntu-12.10-quantal-quetzal-p4) , and yes it is voor xubuntu but its the same solution for ubuntu.
I just installed it and everything seems to be working fine.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Also this link offers too many parts and does not specifically fix the problem at hand.